# Storing data from sensors into hdfs

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, sensors

I am working on a project that involves using **HDFS** for storage and **Spark** for computation.

I need to store data from **sensors** into HDFS in real time.

For example I have a  weather station where the sensor generates data(temperature pression) each 5 seconds. I would like to know how to store these data in hdfs in real time

Answer (score 1):

Writing a lot of small files directly to HDFS may have some undesirable effects, as it affects master node memory usage and may lead to lower processing speed in comparison with batch processing.

Any of your sensor will produce 500k files monthly, so, unless you have very limited number of sensors, I would suggest you to take a look at message brokers. Apache Kafka (https://kafka.apache.org/) is well known one and already bundled in some Hadoop distros. You can use it to "stage" you data and process it in (mini-)batches, for example.

Finally, if you need to process incoming data in real-time maner (CEP and so on), i would recommend to pay attention to Spark Streaming (https://spark.apache.org/streaming/) technology.